# ARM Assembly language code adding 2 integer square matrices?

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm learning ARM Assembly language with STM32F407-DISC1 board. I ran into a problem where I need to write an ARM assembly program that adds two integer square matrices
dimension (N x N), and  calculates C = A + B. And I have to represent the two-dimensional matrix internally in memory as one-dimensional arrays of rows of matrix (sequentially row by row). So, if anyone has some hints, or codes it would be helpful.

I tried this code, but I can't understand it quite well:

```
.global  _start
.section .text.start

_start:
      MOV R0, #2
      LDR R1,=first_array     /*loading the address of first_array[0]*/
      LDR R2,=second_array    /*loading the address of second_array[0]*/
      LDR R7,=final_array     /*loading the address of final_array[0]*/
      MOV R3,#2               /*len of array*/
      MOV R4,#0               /*to store sum*/
check:
      cmp R3,#1               /*like condition in for loop for i>1*/
      BNE loop                /*if R3 is not equal to 1 jump to the loop label(branch if equal)*/
      B _exit                 /*else exit*/
loop:
      LDR R5,[R1],#4          /* loading the values and storing in registers and base register gets updated automatically R1 = R1 + 4*/
      LDR R6,[R2],#4          /*similarly*/
      add R4,R5,R6
      STR R4,[R7],#4          /* storing the values back to the final array*/
      SUB R3,R3,#1             /*decrment value just like i-- in for loop*/
      B check
_exit:
      LDR R7,=final_array     /*before exiting checking the values stored*/
      LDR R1, [R7]            /* R1 = 60*/
      LDR R2, [R7,#4]         /* R2 = 80*/
      LDR R3, [R7,#8]         /* R3 = 100*/
      LDR R4, [R7,#12]        /* R4 = 120*/
      MOV R7, #1              /* terminate syscall, 1*/
      SWI 0                   /* execute syscall*/

.data
first_array:  .word 10,20,30,40
second_array: .word 50,60,70,80
final_array:  .word 0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Your loop only adds 1 pair of numbers since you start counting down from 2 and stop at 1. You need to add 4 numbers, so count down from 4 to 0. Other than that, what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Hi Jester, In loop function it says error "Thumb does not support this adressing mode-''ldr R5,[R1], #4". I'm new to this, and can't really understand what some instructions do..Definitley, thanks for the help!